# why we are passing a varible socket in function below? and what is the value of socket ? is it garbage?

Tags: node.js, sockets

why we are passing a varible socket in function below? and what is the value of socket ? is it garbage

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('A user connected');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`io.on('connection', ...)` announces the incoming connection of a new socket and the `socket` argument to that callback is how you know what the new socket object is for that new connection.

> why we are passing a variable socket in function below

You aren't passing that.  You are simply declaring it as an argument in your callback in the right place so that the underlying socket.io infrastructure will pass the new socket to you when it calls that callback.

> and what is the value of socket ?

It's a socket object for a newly created socket that represents a new incoming connection.

> is is garbage?

No, it's a legit socket.io socket connection that you can call methods on such as `socket.on('somemsg', ...)` to listen for incoming messages on that socket or `socket.emit('somemsg', ...)` to send messages on that socket.